# Can't run a task schedule in Laravel 8 using cron job in BlueHost

Tags: laravel

I am running my web app under Bluehost shared hosting, and I am trying to run a cron job which will call my schedule task in my laravel app. For some reason the scheduler is not being called. These are the commands in Bluehost that I have tried so far:

None of these above commands seems to execute my task scheduler, I have tried calling the command from using artisan command, it works... What do you think this is not working?

**Note :** This is perfectly  working on local server.

**/home3/urbanhq6/public_html/new/app/Console/Kernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Console\Commands\SendReminderEmails;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use App\Console\Commands\SendReminderEmails;
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        App\Console\Commands\SendReminderEmails::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('update:record')
                 ->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

**/home3/urbanhq6/public_html/new/app/Console/Commands/SendReminderEmails.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Booking;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\User;
use App\Mail\ReminderEmailDigest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DB;

class SendReminderEmails extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'update:record';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send email notification to user about reminders.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {

         DB::table('bookings')->update(["check_out" => date("Y-m-d")]);

     }
```

**Cron Job Command**

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home3/urbanhq6/public_html/new/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Is that "Cron Job Command" everything there is in your crontab? (It's missing the schedule expressions)

Comment: try 
```/usr/local/bin/php /home3/urbanhq6/new/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1```

Comment: my whole project folder inside the public_html i think it will be not run without given public_html

Comment: i am getting error in log [2021-10-25 12:01:02] local.ERROR: Target class [App\Console\App\Console\Commands\SendReminderEmails] does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [App\\Console\\App\\Console\\Commands\\SendReminderEmails] does not exist. at /home3/urbanhq6/public_html/new/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:811)